# CSS for pagination wont work after AJAX call return on chrome

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, wordpress, pagination

Well, I have these 2 dropdowns and when it changes it makes ajax call and get new data with pagination. My problem is that, when it finished call and return, somehow css for pagination part wont work the way it supposed to. Although same-thing works fine on firefox. I'm having trouble on chrome.

When i inspect the element css is there but jut not applied. when i uncheck one of the property and check it back again, it works.

**Note** Div with ID "yacht-charter" has more results on actual site, this is for example only.

Any help or suggestions appreciate.

Thanks

```
<div class="row text-center mx-auto p-lg-5"><span class="my-auto mr-5">Filer:</span>
    <form id="luxury-form" class="w-75 d-flex">
        <select id="no_of_passengers" name="no_of_passengers" class="custom-select mr-5">
            <option value="-1"># of Passengers</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
        </select><select id="boat_type" class="custom-select" name="boat_type">
            <option value="all">Boat Type</option>
            <option value="Sailing">Sailing</option>
            <option value="Motor sailor">Motor Sailor</option>
            <option value="Motor">Motor</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row w-100" id="yacht-charter">
    <div class="box col"><img src="https://poseidon-dev.axon-media.com/wp-content/uploads/Irene-Hero.jpg" data-id="2264" alt="2264">
        <div class="yacht-feature-inner"><a href="https://poseidon-dev.axon-media.com/product/irenes">
                <h3 class="heading2 minerva-font">IRENE’S</h3>
                <p>4 Cabins | 4 CREWS | VIEW DATES AND RATES &gt;</p>
            </a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="luxury-pagination" class="row heading3 font-weight-light w-75 mx-auto pt-5 justify-content-center"><span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://poseidon-dev.axon-media.com/destination/greece/luxury-crewed-yacht-charter?paged=2">2</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://poseidon-dev.axon-media.com/destination/greece/luxury-crewed-yacht-charter?paged=3">3</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://poseidon-dev.axon-media.com/destination/greece/luxury-crewed-yacht-charter?paged=4">4</a>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="https://poseidon-dev.axon-media.com/destination/greece/luxury-crewed-yacht-charter?paged=2"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></div><!-- navigation ENDS -->
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>";
        var cur_uri = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>";
        var nonce = "<?php echo wp_create_nonce('luxury_filters'); ?>";
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            jQuery("#no_of_passengers").change(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = {
                    action: 'luxury_filter',
                    passengers : jQuery(this).val(),
                    boat : jQuery('#boat_type').val(),
                    category : 'luxury-charter',
                    uri : cur_uri,
                    cols : 6,
                    nonce: nonce
                };
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        jQuery("#yacht-charter").replaceWith(response);
                    }
                });

            });
            // jQuery("#boat_type").change(function (e) {
                jQuery(document).on("change", "#boat_type", function(e) {
                // e.preventDefault();
                var data = {
                    action: "luxury_filter",
                    boat : jQuery(this).val(),
                    passengers : jQuery("#no_of_passengers").val(),
                    uri : cur_uri,
                    category : "luxury-charter",
                    cols : 6,
                    nonce: nonce,
                    async: false
                };
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type: "post",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        // jQuery("#yacht-charter").html(response);
                        jQuery('#yacht-charter').empty();
                        jQuery('#yacht-charter').append(response);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceWith` Replaces the element itself. Where as `HTML` replaces the content of the element.

So I would change `replaceWith` to `HTML`.

You can also change the empty/append to `HTML` in your other ajax call.